# the path function of svg is not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

i have been trying to implement this code to make a sort of graph where the user clicks on the canvas to create a node and then can again click on any two nodes to have an edge drawn between them and also be able to enter a weight associated to that edge. i cant understand why the path function is not responding. 
probably there could be a syntax error in the statement

pathE1.setAttribute("d", "M  coord1 , coord2  L  coord3 , coord4");

but then i cant figure out what would be the right way.here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<svg id="canvas" height="1260" width="1260">
</svg>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js">

</script>
<script>
    var check;
var circles = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#canvas").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
        var coords = getCoords(e);

        var result = inCircle(coords.x, coords.y);

        if (typeof result === "number") {

            check = result + 1;

        } else {
            draw(coords.x, coords.y);
        }

    });
    $("#canvas").bind("mouseup", function(e) {
        if (!check) {
            console.log('hey');
            return;
        }
        var coords = getCoords(e);
        var result = inCircle(coords.x, coords.y);

        console.log(result);
        if (typeof result === "number") {
            //alert('node up');
            drawConnection(check - 1, result);
        }
        check = 0;

    });




    function getCoords(e) {
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        //alert('x:' +x+ ' y:' +y);
        return {
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
    }

    function inCircle(x, y) {

        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            if (distance(x, y, circles[i].x, circles[i].y) <= 20) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    function draw(x, y) {
        circles.push({
            x: x,
            y: y
        });

        var circle1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
        circle1.setAttribute("cx", x);
        circle1.setAttribute("cy", y);
        circle1.setAttribute("r", 20);
        circle1.style.fill = 'blue';
        circle1.style.stroke = 'blue';
        circle1.style.strokeWidth = '5';
        $('#canvas').append(circle1);
    }

});


function distance(x, y, cx, cy) {
    return Math.sqrt((cx - x) * (cx - x) + (y - cy) * (y - cy));
}

function drawConnection(circ1, circ2) {
    var dist = prompt("enter weight");
    var coord1 = circles[circ1].x,
        coord2 = circles[circ1].y,
        coord3 = circles[circ2].x,
        coord4 = circles[circ2].y;
    var pathE1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    pathE1.setAttribute("d", "M  coord1 , coord2  L  coord3 , coord4");

    pathE1.style.stroke = 'red';
    pathE1.style.strokeWidth = '5';

    $('#canvas').append(pathE1);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pathE1.setAttribute("d", "M  coord1 , coord2  L  coord3 , coord4");
```

is just going to create a path with the text coord1 as its x coordinate and not the **value** of coord1. What you want is

```
pathE1.setAttribute("d", "M " + coord1 + ", " + coord2 + " L " + coord3 + ", " + coord4);
```